# How to aggregate count of rows having the same value in a sequence?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a query that returns data in the following sample:

```
SELECT timestamp, atm_id FROM TRANSACTIONS ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC;
```

## Output

```
TIMESTAMP  | ATM_ID | 
--------------------
2010-01-01 | EP02   |
2010-01-01 | EP02   |
2010-01-28 | EP02   |
2010-02-07 | EP02   |
2010-02-09 | EP11   |
2010-03-19 | EP11   |
2010-03-19 | EP02   |
2010-04-03 | EP05   |
2010-04-30 | EP02   |
```

I know how to group by ATM_ID and put the count in-front of each

```
SELECT
   ATM_ID,
   COUNT(*) CNT
FROM
   TRANSACTIONS
GROUP BY
   ATM_ID;
```

Based on the sample data above, this will yield something like

```
 ATM_ID |  CNT  
---------------
 EP02   |  6
 EP11   |  2
 EP05   |  1
```

However, I am interested in grouping on a different level. If a certain ATM_ID is duplicated in consecutive rows, the number of rows having the same ATM_ID in sequence should be included in the output, even if the same ATM_ID appears later after a different ATM_ID

## Desired Output

```
 ATM_ID |  CNT  
---------------
 EP02   |  4         --Four rows of ATM_ID EP02
 EP11   |  2         --Followed by 2 rows of ATM_ID EP11
 EP02   |  1         --Followed by 1 row of ATM_ID EP02
 EP05   |  1         --Followed by 1 row of ATM_ID EP05
 EP02   |  1         --Followed by 1 row of ATM_ID EP02
```

Ignore the comments on the right, these are just for clarifications, not part of the output.
Is that possible?

PS: The answer below by Syed Aladeen gives the output with the correct count, but with the wrong order. I create an SQL fiddle for convenience:

## [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8649a7/4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Oracle 12c+: pattern matching
with s(dt, atm_id) as (
select to_date('2010-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP02' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP02' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-01-28', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP02' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-02-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP02' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-02-09', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP11' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-03-19', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP11' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-03-19', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP02' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-04-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP05' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-04-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP02' from dual)
select *
from s
match_recognize (
order by dt
measures v.atm_id as atm_id,
count(v.atm_id) as cnt,
first(dt) as min_dt,
last (dt) as max_dt
pattern (v+)
define v as v.atm_id = first(atm_id)
);

ATM_        CNT MIN_DT              MAX_DT
---- ---------- ------------------- -------------------
EP02          4 2010-01-01 00:00:00 2010-02-07 00:00:00
EP11          2 2010-02-09 00:00:00 2010-03-19 00:00:00
EP02          1 2010-03-19 00:00:00 2010-03-19 00:00:00
EP05          1 2010-04-03 00:00:00 2010-04-03 00:00:00
EP02          1 2010-04-30 00:00:00 2010-04-30 00:00:00

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01

-- Oracle 8i+: window sort + window buffer + group by [+ order by]
with s(dt, atm_id) as (
select to_date('2010-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP02' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP02' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-01-28', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP02' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-02-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP02' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-02-09', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP11' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-03-19', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP11' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-03-19', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP02' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-04-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP05' from dual union all
select to_date('2010-04-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'EP02' from dual)
select atm_id, count(*) cnt, min(dt) min_dt, max(dt) as max_dt
from
  (select dt, atm_id, count(lg) over (order by dt) ct, lg
    from
     (select dt, atm_id, decode(atm_id, lag(atm_id) over (order by dt), null, 1) lg
      from s
     )
  )
group by ct, atm_id
order by min_dt;

ATM_        CNT MIN_DT              MAX_DT
---- ---------- ------------------- -------------------
EP02          4 2010-01-01 00:00:00 2010-02-07 00:00:00
EP11          1 2010-02-09 00:00:00 2010-02-09 00:00:00
EP02          1 2010-03-19 00:00:00 2010-03-19 00:00:00
EP11          1 2010-03-19 00:00:00 2010-03-19 00:00:00
EP05          1 2010-04-03 00:00:00 2010-04-03 00:00:00
EP02          1 2010-04-30 00:00:00 2010-04-30 00:00:00

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: I could not get it to work.. Can you create an SQL Fiddle, or use the one I created? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8649a7/6

Comment: 1) My answer consists 2 examples. Which of them you try?
2) First example runs on Oracle 12, SQL Fiddle supports only 11.
3) Your created table with id column but my example works with dt.

Comment: the date is not important in the output, I just added it to show the sequence. So the id indicates the order in a shorter way

Comment: I think you are very lazy if you still didn't try my second example.

Comment: I did try the second example, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8649a7/21 I need to select the data from the table, and to use the id instead of the timestamp dt

Comment: Check your count(*) function. In my example it has a different argument.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select atm_id , count(*) 
from (select TRANSACTIONS.*,
     (row_number() over (order by id) -
      row_number() over (partition by atm_id order by id)
     ) as grp
from TRANSACTIONS
) TRANSACTIONS
group by grp, atm_id order by max(id)
```

Comment: I tried that and it somehow works, but the order in the output is not the correct one. Please take a look at this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8649a7/4